# Handle mat-radio-button form value accessor in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat radio group component that renders also a list of form fields

```
<form *ngIf="myRatesForm.controls.items.controls.length > 0" [formGroup]="myRatesForm">
  <mat-radio-group formArrayName="items">
    <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let myRate of myRatesForm.controls.items.controls; let i = index">
      <mat-radio-button [checked]="myRate.isFavorite" formControlName="isFavorite" [value]="myRate">
        <div class="flex">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <input formControlName="name" matInput placeholder="Taux" />
          </mat-form-field>
          <div (click)="inputFocus($event)">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <input formControlName="rateValue" matInput placeholder="Taux" />
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-radio-button>
    </div>
  </mat-radio-group>
</form>
```

In my ts file I'm creating a dynamic formArray

```
itemsForm: FormArray = this.fb.array([]);
myRatesForm = new FormGroup({
  items: this.itemsForm,
});
constructor(private store: Store, private pricesSelector: PricesSelector, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

myRates: MyRates[] = [];
subscription$: Subscription = new Subscription();
favoriteRate: MyRates;
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.subscription$ = this.store.select(this.pricesSelector.getPriceTaxValue).subscribe(data => {
    this.myRates = data.myRates;
    this.myRates.map(rate => {
      this.myRatesForm.controls.items.push(
        this.fb.group({
          name: [rate.name, Validators.required],
          rateValue: [rate.rateValue, Validators.required],
          isFavorite: [rate.isFavorite],
        })
      );
    });
  });
}
```

Actually the Name and the rateValue formControls are working .

But the radioButton **isFavorite** is not working . I'm getting this error

> NG01203: No value accessor for form control path: 'items -> 2 ->
> isFavorite'. Find more...

I think [because](https://v15.material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview) `FormControlName` is not set on `mat-radio-group`

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio group is a logical grouping of mat radio buttons, so we need to move the radio group to a separate form control `favourited` this will contain the selected value, then we can render the radio buttons without form control name!

working example provided with code and stackblitz!

code

ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

/**
 * @title Radios with ngModel
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'radio-ng-model-example',
  templateUrl: 'radio-ng-model-example.html',
  styleUrl: 'radio-ng-model-example.css',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatInputModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
})
export class RadioNgModelExample {
  itemsForm: FormArray = this.fb.array([]);
  myRatesForm = new FormGroup({
    favourited: new FormControl(),
    items: this.itemsForm,
  });
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  myRates: any[] = [];
  subscription$: Subscription = new Subscription();
  favoriteRate: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myRates = [
      { name: 'test1', rateValue: 1, isFavorite: true },
      { name: 'test2', rateValue: 2, isFavorite: false },
      { name: 'test3', rateValue: 3, isFavorite: false },
    ];
    this.myRates.map((rate) => {
      this.myRatesForm.controls.items.push(
        this.fb.group({
          name: [rate.name, Validators.required],
          rateValue: [rate.rateValue, Validators.required],
          isFavorite: [rate.isFavorite],
        })
      );
    });
  }
}
```

html

```
{{myRatesForm.value | json}}

<form
  *ngIf="myRatesForm.controls.items.controls.length > 0"
  [formGroup]="myRatesForm"
>
  <mat-radio-group formControlName="favourited">
    <div formArrayName="items">
      <div
        [formGroupName]="i"
        *ngFor="let myRate of myRatesForm.controls.items.controls; let i = index"
      >
        <mat-radio-button
          [value]="myRates[i]"
          [checked]="myRates[i].isFavorite"
        ></mat-radio-button>
        <div class="flex">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <input formControlName="name" matInput placeholder="Taux" />
          </mat-form-field>
          <div>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <input formControlName="rateValue" matInput placeholder="Taux" />
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-radio-group>
</form>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ze5xrb?file=src%2Fexample%2Fradio-ng-model-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Fradio-ng-model-example.ts)